# Spring Boot Reading Properties Files Based on classpath arg

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have created a standalone boot.jar that I need to start integrating into our higher environments. 
Each environment has a property file that contains database specific connection information. Since this does not live in my boot jar, I would like to somehow add the path to this database.properties file and then read the entries based on key. Used to create a bean like so:

```
<bean id="propertyLoader" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
<property name="locations">
        <value>classpath:application.properties</value>
</property>
```

but with boot, I am not sure how to do this: But I want to point to this below property example and pull out my values and somehow populate the application.properties values that I hardcoded in dev.

```
server:/config/database.properties
jdbc.username=TEST
jdbc.password=CHANGEME
```

Updating my application.properites:

```
spring.datasource.username='jdbc.username'
spring.datasource.password='jdbc.password'
```

Something like that do I can parameterize my application.properties file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SpringBoot offers profiles, which basically allows you to have separate application.properties file for each environment.

You can have something like this:

```
public interface DataSourceConfig {}

@Component
@Profile("dev")
public DevDataSourceConfig implements DataSourceConfig{}

@Component
@Profile("prod")
public ProdDataSourceConfig implements DataSourceConfig{}
```

If you have the spring profile `"dev"` set as active, only the `DevDataSourceConfig` bean will be instantiated and in Spring `Environment` the properties that will be injected, will be read from the `application-dev.properties` file.

Similarly when you have the `"prod"` profile activated, only the `ProdDataSourceConfig` will be instantiated and the properties will be loaded from `application-prod.properties` file.

This allows you to have:

```
---
application-dev.properties
spring.datasource.username='jdbc.username'
spring.datasource.password='jdbc.password'
---
application-prod.properties
spring.datasource.username='PROD_jdbc.username'
spring.datasource.password='PROD_jdbc.password'
```

If you want to load the configuration from a custom location on the file system - you can check how to pass the location with command line arguments ([docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-application-property-files))

Example:

```
java -jar boot.jar --spring.config.location=classpath:/database.properties
```

Answer (score 1):

you already told you can not have property files inside your jar, still there are multiple options.

1> passing a property file for respective env.

```
java -jar myproject.jar --spring.config.location=classpath:/database.properties
```

2> pass properties while calling the jar

```
java -jar app.jar --spring.datasource.username="jdbc.username" --spring.datasource.password="jdbc.password"
```

[Read a lot of other options here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html)  `

I would go with option 1, because passing credentials is never advisable in arguements.